# Graphing $y=x+\sin(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I've been trying to learn how to graph some miscellaneous functions and I came across this. I put it in [*Desmos*](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and
[this is what I ended up with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHnA3.jpg).

Can you let me know how did the graph get its shape? And how can one graph such type of functions on their own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function has two parts.

The $x$ is a line at 45° and it is shown as a dashed line in your post.

The $\sin x$ is a sine wave that fluctuates around the 0 value by $\pm 1$ in a wavy pattern.

Put them together, and you get a curve going uphill but also fluctuates by $\pm 1$ in a wavy pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The input values for the graph are measured in radians by default.  Between 0 and $\pi$ radians, the sine function's outputs have positive values, so when added to the number of radians produces values above the line y = x.  Between $\pi$ and $2\pi$ radians, the sine function has negative outputs which when added to the number of radians produces values below the line y = x.  This pattern then repeats around the line y = x in each horizontal direction, just like the sine function itself does.

Answer (score 0):

The graph for $y = x + \sin x$ is the superposition of the lines $y = x$ and the sine curve $y = \sin x$.  When you combine one graph and the other through a mathematical operation, the new graph takes on the characteristics of each of the original graphs.

In your Desmos graph, $y = x + \sin x$ can be thought of as the regular sine function $y = \sin x$ rotated $45°$ clockwise.